# Changing blackjack ace if over 21

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a RPi blackjack project. Before I add the Pi into the mix, I want to get the Python code working by itself. The problem is mainly the Ace. I can't figure out a way to get it to switch to a "low ace" if, after hitting, the total goes over 21.

I believe that it might actually be switching, but when added up, the cards still go over. I think it has something to do with my `overflow()` function.

```
import random

alt = {"A(l)" : 1}

nums = {
    "A" : 11,
    "2" : 2,
    "3" : 3,
    "4" : 4,
    "5" : 5,
    "6" : 6,
    "7" : 7,
    "8" : 8,
    "9" : 9,
    "10": 10,
    "J" : 10,
    "Q" : 10,
    "K" : 10
}
suits = ["D", "H", "S", "C"]

playerCards = []
dealerCards = []


def overflow(cards):
    try:
        ace = cards.index("A")
    except:
        ace = -1
    if sum([nums[card] for card in cards]) > 21:
        if ace != -1:
            cards[ace] = "A(l)"
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

while True:
    winner = "none"
    playerCards.clear()
    dealerCards.clear()

    playerCards.append(random.choice(list(nums.keys())))
    playerCards.append(random.choice(list(nums.keys())))

    dealerCards.append(random.choice(list(nums.keys())))

    print("Player:")
    print(" ".join(playerCards), ":", sum([nums[card] for card in playerCards]))
    print("Dealer:")
    print(" ".join(dealerCards))
    print()

    while True:
        if not overflow(playerCards):
            hitStand = input("'hit' or 'stand'?: ")

            if(hitStand == "hit"):
                playerCards.append(random.choice(list(nums.keys())))
                print(" ".join(playerCards), ":",
                      sum([nums[card] for card in playerCards]))
                print()
            else:
                break
        else:
            winner = "dealer"
            print()
            print("Dealer wins")
            print("-----------")
            break

    while sum([nums[card] for card in dealerCards]) < 17 and winner == "none":
        print()
        print("Dealer:")
        if not overflow(dealerCards):
            dealerCards.append(random.choice(list(nums.keys())))
            print(" ".join(dealerCards), ":", sum([nums[card] for card in dealerCards]))
        else:
            winner = "player"
            print()
            print("Player wins")
            print("-----------")
            break

    if winner == "none":
        if(sum([nums[card] for card in playerCards]) ==
           sum([nums[card] for card in dealerCards])):
            print()
            print("Tie")
            print("-----------")
            break
        elif (sum([nums[card] for card in playerCards]) >
              sum([nums[card] for card in dealerCards]) or overflow(dealerCards)):
            winner = "player"
            print()
            print("Player wins")
            print("-----------")
            continue
        else:
            winner = "dealer"
            print()
            print("Dealer wins")
            print("-----------")
            continue
```

Comment: I don't understand; when `overflow()` encounters a value above 21, it sets `cards[ace] = "A(l)"` but then does not re-compute the sum, and doesn't return either a `True` or `False` value. Can you explain why you're not re-computing the sum or returning anything in that case?

Comment: I now return false after setting A to A(l), but now I realize that I cannot use two dictionaries. As for recomputing, would I do that as an if-elif-else when I check overflow?

Comment: Why would you return false if you don't yet know if the sum is still 21 or less? You may consider computing the sum in another function, and just calling that function again if you've determined that there's at least one ace in the hand. But you still aren't considering the case of a player having more than one ace. I think you might need to design your program on paper and think of all such scenarios; it's much easier to decouple design from implementation rather than try to figure both out at once.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be that complicated.

```
def overflow(cards):
    val = sum([nums[card] for card in cards)
    if val > 21 and 'A' in cards:
        val -= 10
    return val > 21
```

Notice that this condition is traditionally called "bust", not "overflow".

I would probably do two functions:

```
def score(cards):
    val = sum([nums[card] for card in cards)
    if val > 21 and 'A' in cards:
        val -= 10
    return val

def overflow(cards):
    return score(cards) > 21
```

Comment: This very nearly works perfectly. The one issue I found playtesting is that if 2 aces are in the same hand, the second one is counted as an 11.
I changed the code so that the correct sum is printed out, and so that the busting is checked with the 'overflow' function.

Comment: Since only one A can be an 11, perhaps it would be smarter to have your `num` array have 'A' == 1, then have the test be `if val < 12 and 'A' in cards:` / `val += 10`.

Comment: Works like a charm! I will be back if I find any other bugs, but so far I haven't found any issues.